# Why do I need org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams, if I'm not making a reactive web application?

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, wildfly-18

I'd like to deploy a spring-boot 2.2.2.RELEASE application onto a Wildfly 18 application server.

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ropi.psf</groupId>
            <artifactId>psf-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I try to deploy it, I get the following error:

```
2020-03-14 23:40:01,657 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."psf-frontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."psf-frontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.InjectionTargets.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargets.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module "deployment.psf-frontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1471)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.checkDeclaringClassLoadable(Reflections.java:427)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$null$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder.get(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getCastValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:177)
    ... 12 more
```

This problem can be solved by including:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

which I really don't want to, since I'm not making a reactive web appliaction. Is there a better workaround/solution to this problem? Or is it a bug?

Comment: how did you solve this? I have the same problem, forced to add reactive streams jar and that cause a zillion problems

Comment: I faced the same issue, and had to add the reactive jar too. Is there a better way? I am doing nothing that needs the reactive jar. Please suggest